# Searching a MySQL database for tags

Tags: php, mysql, search, tags

I'm working on creating a system to allow users to upload items and add 'tags' to them to help them be visible in searches.  Currently, I have a database that works like this:

```
id|title|tags
```

Where `tags` is a comma-separated list of tags the user has entered themself.  I've read that this is a terrible way to do it, <s>but having a tags table and storing each ID along with the item record is basically the same thing.</s>

How could I run a search to return the most relevant results first?  I'm using this at the moment, which works, but doesn't sort by relevancy: `SELECT * FROM items WHERE tags LIKE '%$tag%' LIMIT 0,20";` where `$tag` is just a tag, no commas (it's inside a loop).

Comment: `... is basically the same thing...`, until you have to sort by relevancy, sort by a specific tag, search for more than one tag at a time or get bad performance and add an index to the field.

Comment: How do you define relevancy? There is no order by in your query, so it just returns the records in the order of your primary index (usually the primary key). Even if you split it out into a table, you'd still have to define relevancy.

Comment: @Sam I'd define relevancy as how many tags were matched to the item.  If the user types 3 tags in the search, and an item in the results has all 3 tags, I want that one to be first, not in the order they are in the database.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`having a tags table and storing each ID along with the item record is basically the same thing`

NO. NO. NO. It's definitely not the same thing.

You take your "comma separated listed" version, and try to come up with the queries to accomplish these problems:

1. delete tag ID #7 from all titles
2. How many titles use tag #87

With a properly normalized table:

1. DELETE FROM users_tags WHERE tag_id=7
2. SELECT count(*) FROM users_tags WHERE tag_id = 87

With your version:

1. UPDATE users_tags SET tags=.... insert massively ugly string operation here ...
2. SELECT count(*) FROM users_tags WHERE tag_id=87 OR tag_id='87,%' OR tag_id LIKE '%,87,%' or tag_id LIKE '%,87'

see the difference?

Comment: I see.  But wouldn't your normalized table example only allow one tag per item?  I'm looking to have many tags, similar to StackOverflow itself or YouTube.  Sorry!

Comment: @PGR so you would need 3 tables: items(id, title) tags(id, tag) itemTags(id, itemid, tagid)

Comment: @pgr: exactly what john boker said. 3 tables, with the 3rd one being the link/pivot table that links users with tags. read up about "many to many" relationships.

Comment: @MarcB Thank you guys, I've basically never gotten my feet wet with MySQL before, this will be interesting!  Thanks for your help!

Comment: it's not just mysql. this applies to ALL relational database. they exist to relate data. when you stuff multiple different values together into a single field, you're taking away the "relate" part of relational - now the db can't do the stuff it's designed for, because it can only relate single bits of data at a time, not "globs" of data.