# How to extract one value from imploded array in MySQL row

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using implode to insert few values into one row in MySQL database.

```
implode(' ', $_POST['tag']);
```

Assuming that I have table named `product` with row named `tags` with 3 different values that inserted inside like this:

```
usb adapter charger
```

I have tried using this method using like operator (`%`), but that didn't worked.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE tags='%usb%'";
```

How can I extract only one value from the imploded array using WHERE in mysql query?

Comment: `LIKE` not `=` if you want to use wild cards

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad may be worth a read.

Comment: "I'm using implode to insert few values into one row"  Let me stop you right there.  Re-design your database to store those values in another table with columns id, productid, and tagid.  This will not only remove this current issue, but save you many other headaches.

Comment: @PatrickQ I'm inserting tags to one row, meaning one product might have couple of tags, I'm not inserting the entire table values into one row.

Comment: @YotamDahan  I understand that.  And what you're doing is quite ill-advised.  See the link provided by Nigel.

Comment: @PatrickQ But I assume it's doable right? I'm using this method just to filter tags in my system, there wont be any use for that column if I get it right.

Comment: @YotamDahan  Let's say you tag some things with "pan" because, well, they are pans.  Let's say you tag some other things as "panther" because they are shirts or mugs or whatever with a panther on them.  When you search for pans, do you also want to get all products with panthers on them?  Your current strategy, assuming you change `=` to `LIKE` will have that result.  Searches will also be slow(er), as they will not take advantage of indexes.

Comment: @PatrickQ Alright then, I'll change the database structure, but how do you suggest I'll connect each tag to his product?

Comment: @YotamDahan  Exactly the way my first comment showed.  You'll have a `products` table, a `tags` table, and a `product_tag` table (or some other similar name).  `products` has `id`, `name`, `description`, etc.  `tags` has `id`, and `name`.  `product_tag` has `id`, `productid`, and `tagid`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A better way to search for tags in mysql table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39239521/a-better-way-to-search-for-tags-in-mysql-table)

Comment: There are a  number of other related questions on here including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14528763/searching-a-mysql-database-for-tags)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the comments about re-designing the database. At first read it seems that using `LIKE` would definitely get the result you want but after reading @Patrick Q's pan - panther example, it makes a lot sense that `LIKE` is not really a good solution. There are ways to get exactly the tag string you're looking for but it may hurt the performance and the query will be longer and complex. Hence the following are to demonstrate how the query would look like with your current `tags` data value:

```
MySQL query:

SELECT tags,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(tags,' ',FIND_IN_SET('usb',REPLACE(tags,' ',','))),' ',-1) v 
FROM   mytable
HAVING v = 'usb';
```

As you can see, there are a few functions being used just to get the exact string from the data cell. Since your example data was separating with spaces and `FIND_IN_SET` identify value separation by comma, `REPLACE` take place on the `tags` column first to replace spaces with comma. Then with `SUBSTRING_INDEX` twice to get the string using the location extracted in `FIND_IN_SET`. Finally at the end `HAVING` to get only the tag you're looking for.

Further demo here : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/joDa7MNcQL2RakTgBa7qBM/3